# solve In Matlab a quadratic equation with very small coefficients

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm implementing a code in matlab to solve quadratic equations, using the resolvent formula:

[image]

Here´s the code:

```
clear all 
format short 
a=1; b=30000000.001; c=1/4; 
rdelta=sqrt(b^2-4*a*c); 
x1=(-b+rdelta)/(2*a);
x2=(-b-rdelta)/(2*a);
fprintf(' Roots of the polynomial %5.3f x^2 + %5.3f x+%5.3f \n',a,b,c)  
fprintf ('x1= %e\n',x1)
fprintf ('x2= %e\n\n',x2)
valor_real_x1= -8.3333e-009;
valor_real_x2= -2.6844e+007;

error_abs_x1 = abs (valor_real_x1-x1);
error_abs_x2 = abs (valor_real_x2-x2);

error_rel_x1 = abs (error_abs_x1/valor_real_x1);
error_rel_x2 = abs (error_abs_x2/valor_real_x2);

fprintf(' absolute_errorx1 = |real value - obtained value| = |%e - %e| = %e \n',valor_real_x1,x1,error_abs_x1)  
fprintf(' absolute_errorx2 = |real value - obtained value| = |%e - %e| = %e \n\n',valor_real_x2,x2,error_abs_x2) 

fprintf(' relative error_x1 = |absolut error / real value| = |%e / %e| = %e \n',error_abs_x1,valor_real_x1,error_rel_x1 ) 
 fprintf(' relative_error_x2 = |absolut error / real value|  = |%e / %e| = %e \n',error_abs_x2,valor_real_x2,error_rel_x2)
```

The problem I have is that it gives me an exact solution, ie for values ​​a = 1, b = 30000000,001 c = 1/4, the values ​​of the roots are:

```
Roots of the polynomial 1.000 x^2 + 30000000.001 x+0.250 
 x1= -9.313226e-009
 x2= -3.000000e+007
```

Knowing that the exact value of the roots of the polynomial are:

```
x1= -8.3333e-009
x2= -2.6844e+007
```

Which gives me the following errors in the absolute and relative precision of the calculations:

```
 absolute_errorx1 = |real value - obtained value| = |-8.333300e-009 - -9.313226e-009| = 9.799257e-010 
 absolute_errorx2 = |real value - obtained value| = |-2.684400e+007 - -3.000000e+007| = 3.156000e+006 

 relative error_x1 = |absolut error / real value| = |9.799257e-010 / -8.333300e-009| = 1.175916e-001 
 relative_error_x2 = |absolut error / real value|  = |3.156000e+006 / -2.684400e+007| = 1.175682e-001
```

My question is: Is there an optimum method to obtain the roots of a quadratic equation?, ie I can make changes to my code to reduce the relative error between the expected solution and the resulting solution?

Comment: just one thing: when you think you have the "real" solutions, check them with the girard relations (we call them like that on the latin speaking world, I think in anglo-saxonic countries they are called Newton Identity or sth like that). It seems that woodchips answered your question nicely, but just recall also that in the double precision world, your actual mantissa precision is 2^53, mess with differences greater than that, or smaller than your exponent, and you end up with garbage

Comment: 2+2^54 == 2+2^54 +1 try this in Matlab, or this 2^54 - (2^54 - 1) == 0, and see what's the return

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the quadratic formula directly in this cases results in a large loss of numerical precision from subtracting two values of very similar magnitude. This is because the expression

```
sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)
```

is nearly the same as b. So you should use only one of these two roots, the one that does not involve subtracting two very close values, and for the other root you can use (for instance) the fact that the product of roots of a quadratic is c/a. I'll let you fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 3):

Why does this sound like a homework problem from a first class in numerical analysis?

It has been a while since I was that young, but as I recall there is a trick. Anyway, you are wrong. The true roots of that polynomial are

```
solve('x^2 + 30000000.001*x + 0.25')
ans =
          -30000000.000999991666666666944442
 -0.0000000083333333330555578703796293981491
```

How well does roots do here?

```
p = [1 30000000.001 1/4];
format long g
roots(p)
ans =
             -30000000.001
     -8.33333333305556e-09
```

That actually seems pretty good. How does HPF do?

```
DefaultNumberOfDigits 64
a = hpf(1);
b = hpf('30000000.001');
c = hpf('0.25');

r1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
r1 =
-0.000000008333333333055557870379629398149125529835186899898569329967

r2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
r2 =
-30000000.000999991666666666944442129620370601850874470164813100101
```

Yep, HPF works nicely enough too.

So what happens when you use double precision numbers and the standard formula? Yeah, crapola arrives.

```
a = 1;
b = 30000000.001;
c = 0.25;

>> r1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
r1 =
     -7.45058059692383e-09

>> r2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
r2 =
             -30000000.001
```

Again, massive subtractive cancellation eats away at the result. (I seem to recall that was the problem you had in your last question.)

There is a trick you can use. See that the large solution was well estimated, just not the one near zero. So, what happens if you solved for the roots of fliplr(p) using the quadratic formula? How does this solve your problem? What transformation is implicitly done when you do that? (Sorry, but I won't do your homework. I think the above was enough of a hint anyway.)

Comment: Is not exactly homework, is part of a scientific computing lab, and I want to understand in detail what is happening. btw, I would like to know how to access your tool HPF. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: HPF is not yet posted on the FEX. I'm revising it to use migits, but that means rewriting it nearly from scratch in part. Note that you can also use the Java BigDecimal tool. I looked at it, but it has some flaws of its own that I dislike. Until then, consider the trick I suggested at the end of my response. It is an implicit transformation of the polynomial, so then you must transform the roots that result.

Comment: @Melkhiah66 - Well, I've finally got HPF into a form that I consider a beta release. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class-currently-in-beta-release

Answer (score 1):

i think your "real" values might be wrong (or maybe it's a precision thing... I dunno)

```
a*(valor_real_x1^2)+b*(valor_real_x1)+c

ans =

   9.9999e-07

a*(valor_real_x2^2)+b*(valor_real_x2)+c

ans =

  -8.4720e+13
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice formula for this problem:

```
var q = sqrt(c*a)/b;
var f = .5 + .5 *sqrt(1-4*q*q);
var x1=-b*f/a;
var x2=-c/(f*b);
```